# SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
       jQuery('#pworld,#pauto,#psubmit').attr({
       href: 'mailto:contact@google.com?subject=test',
       class: 'pullup'
  });
  };
```

The above code seems to work fine but I get an error on IE8 on the line `class: 'pullup'`

SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number

Why is that?

Comment: `class` is a keyword, you'll have to make it a string, like `"class":`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `class` as a property name in an object literal without quoting it.

```
"class": 'pullup'
```

should work. In one of his essays (or whatever they are) Crockford explains that this restriction is not necessary for syntactic disambiguation, but the rule's there anyway.

Comment: ok thanks - had no idea but it works fine in all other browsers

Comment: @JoannaMikalai yes I suppose they've loosened up the rules.